# is this xml correct

Tags: xml, jquery, solr, solrj, jquery-xml

Is there any problem with this xml??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <results xmlns="http://www.host.com/type">
        <result>
            <attr value="" name="TitleBlock1"/>
            <attr value="" name="TitleBlock2"/>
            <attr value="Introductory" name="rev"/>
        </result>
    </results>
```

As when I am getting response back from the server.. and when I checked in firebug, it is saying that

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{3c06a977-b497-5c43f72584c8} Line Number 1, Column 1:

^
```

As I am not getting any response back from the server, and also I am getting 200 Ok request for this url `https://rest-search.host.com/machine/search/meta?id=TR` but no response back. This is below code

```
var search_agile_metadata= 'https://rest-search.host.com/m/search/meta?id=';
var on_show_info_agile = function() {

                request_meta_info = $.ajax({
                url: data + current_doc_info.id,
                type: 'GET',
                success: data,
                error: data

        });
    };
```

So thought to change the url to get the json response. And when I change the dataType to script then I get the response back but with the error `missing ; before statement`. I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: It is valid: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Comment: @Mike Swift, then what's wrong with the response coming back from the server..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the server response missing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header which will allow your javascript to read the response?

Comment: @CrazyDart, yes it is missing?? so what should I do??

Comment: @CrazyDart, so is there any way that I can modify the response header to include that.. And If I am working on the server than this error will be resolved??

Comment: Client side, I dont think you can do anything.  If you are able to get at the code server side, add the header... Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: some resources: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303(v=vs.85).aspx
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control

Comment: @CrazyDart, thanks for the information,now I understand what is happening?? so how can I add this header, any example will be appreciatd.. as I have no clue how to do this...

Comment: You cant add it unless you control the server side code.  If you work for qualcomm I would guess you need to talk with the project manager to get it on the backlog.  If you dont, you can send them an email and tell them all about it, and maybe they will care.

If you enjoyed your experience today, please upvote me and click that little check mark so I can feed my family ;-)

Comment: @CrazyDart, can you explain me one thing.. If i choose dataType as script then I get the response back but with the error `missing ; before statement` for the xml. Why is it so??

Comment: can you edit your post where you mentioned my company name as my company has asked me to remove those things as soon as possible so any help will be appreciated on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciated your help.